# Getting foreign key column values easily in PDO (JOIN on INSERT)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have two tables, 'events' and 'activities', where events has a foreign key 'activity' which is the id of that activity. When I'm inserting into the database, the data I get from POST is the activity's 'name' column so currently I'm doing a SELECT to find the id based on the activity name.

However my plan is to add foreign keys in a similar way to the other columns of 'events' and that would make the code look very unpretty (and probably slow) if I had to look up all of their ids manually. Is there any way to get the foreign key column values with a JOIN like you can do with SELECT? Or what would be the best way in this situation?

```
$events = $_POST["events"];

$sql = "INSERT INTO events (user, activity, tutor, place, start, end) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
$stmt= $conn->prepare($sql);

foreach($events as $row) {
    $query = "SELECT id FROM activities WHERE name = ?";
    $sth = $conn->prepare($query);
    $sth->execute([$row["activity"]]);
    $res = $sth->fetch();

    $stmt->execute([$row["user"], $res["id"], $row["tutor"], $row["place"], 
    $row["start"], $row["end"]]);
}
```

Comment: Presumably, activity comes from a drop down list? Normally, you'd just associate each item on the list with a 'value' equivalent to its own id.

Comment: @Strawberry that makes sense, yes the data comes from drop-down lists. Thanks!